# Please how to do this basic thing with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Imagine that I have a tensor like that as input:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

And I want to output this:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

By any way using only tf operations (convert to numpy, do operation, and switch back to tf tensor is forbidden because I'm doing gradient descent with tf optimizers)

Comment: Are you rotating the rows or shifting zeros in?

Comment: @NPE Rotating or shifting is equivalent in my case, since I am guaranteed to have as many non-zero numbers as zero numbers. That said, the non-zero block is actually a block of random numbers.

Comment: Please add that to your question so that readers don't have to read the comments to fully understand the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a zero-fill -- it is straightforward to replace with a random fill.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.zeros((8, 13), dtype=np.float32)
x[:, :6] = 1
x = tf.constant(x)

s0 = tf.shape(x)[0]
# add an extra zero column on the right
x2 = tf.concat([x, tf.zeros((s0, 1), dtype=x.dtype)], axis=-1)
# flatten the result and remove as many elements as we just added
x2 = tf.reshape(x2, [-1])[:-s0]
# reshape the result to the original shape
x2 = tf.reshape(x2, [s0, -1])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(x.eval())
print(x2.eval())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user1735003

Another way to do it that I found:

```
def roll(tensor):
    T=tf.expand_dims(tf.zeros([tensor.shape[1]),0)
        for i in range(tensor.shape[0]):
            row=tf.manip.roll(tensor[i,], shift=i, axis=0)
            T = tf.concat([T,row],axis=1)
    return T
```